# I want to make my android application keep the screen on, but only at certain times. How do I do this?

Tags: android

I'm aware of 2 methods to make the screen stay on:

- getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); in the .java file
- android:keepScreenOn="true" in the layout xml tag

It seems that this keeps the screen on well, but I basically need to know how to reverse one of these so that I can toggle between keeping the screen on and setting it to the normal timeout period.

Answer (score 1):

For the first thing, you could use [`clearFlags`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#clearFlags%28int%29).

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

For the second thing, use [`setKeepScreenOn(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29) in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a WakeLock - see [PowerManager.WakeLock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

You can acquire different types by calling [newWakeLock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) using `PowerManager`

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the following single line to prevent screen timeout while your app is running
                        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);